# Swift protocol initializer precludes adding more stored properties to struct

Tags: swift, initialization, swift-protocols

**TL;DR**:

I want a protocol to provide default `init` behavior, but the compiler resists adopters adding more stored properties. I solved this with composition instead of inheritance, but what's wrong with my original approach?

**Motivation**

I want to automate the transformation of objects from design specifications to runtime specs. I use the example of scaling a `CGSize` but the intent is more general than just geometric layout. (IOW e.g. my solution won't be to adopt/reject/rewrite autolayout.)

**Code**

You can paste this right into a Playground, and it will run correctly.

```
protocol Transformable {
    var size : CGSize { get }               // Will be set automatically;
    static var DESIGN_SPEC : CGSize { get } // could be any type.
    init(size: CGSize)                      // Extension will require this.
}

// A simple example of transforming.
func transform(_ s: CGSize) -> CGSize  {
    CGSize(width: s.width/2, height: s.height/2)
}

// Add some default behavior.
// Am I sinning to want to inherit implementation?
extension Transformable {
    init() { self.init(size: transform(Self.DESIGN_SPEC)) }
     // User gets instance with design already transformed. No muss, fuss.
}

// Adopt the protocol...
struct T : Transformable {
    let size: CGSize
    static let DESIGN_SPEC = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
}

// ...and use it.
let t = T()
t.size  // We get (5,5) as expected.
```

But every Eden must have its snake. I want a `Transformable` with another property:

```
struct T2 : Transformable {
    // As before.
    let size: CGSize
    static let DESIGN_SPEC = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)

    let i : Int   // This causes all sorts of trouble.
}
```

Whaa? `Type 'T2' does not conform to protocol 'Transformable'`

We have lost the synthesized initializer that sets the `size` member.

So... we put it back:

```
struct T3 : Transformable {
    // As before.
    let size: CGSize
    static let DESIGN_SPEC = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    let i : Int

    init(size: CGSize) {
        self.size = size
        self.i = 0  // But this is a hard-coded value.
    }
}
```

But now our new member is statically determined. So we try adding another initializer:

```
struct T4 : Transformable {
    // As before.
    let size: CGSize
    static let DESIGN_SPEC = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    let i : Int
    init(size: CGSize) { self.size = size ; self.i = 0 }

    // Try setting 'i':
    init(i: Int) {
        self.init() // Get the design spec properly transformed.

        self.i = i  // 'let' property 'i' may not be initialized directly;
    }               // use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead
}
```

Declaring `i` as `var` shuts the compiler up. But `i` is immutable, and I want i that way. Explain to me why what I want is so wrong... This page is too small to include all the variations I tried, but perhaps I have missed the simple answer.

Comment: Are you sinning to want to inherit implementation? No, but.. Pardon if this sounds a bit glib but you could use classes for this. Thanks for the question though it brought me to some good reading https://forums.swift.org/t/overriding-protocol-default-implementation/5147/8, https://forums.swift.org/t/default-protocol-implementation-inheritance-behaviour-the-current-situation-and-what-if-anything-should-be-done-about-it/28049/13

Comment: Thanks for the reference. You may also like https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/wcook/papers/InheritanceSubtyping90/CookPOPL90.pdf Or Barbara Liskov or Bertrand Meyer.